# Toggling Images for Active Links with React.js

Tags: reactjs, image, toggle, navbar

I am currently trying to learn React.js for a school project and am having trouble with toggling images in combination with active links (I have searched high and low for a tutorial with no avail).
 My site is going to look similar to the old time Kingdom Hearts 1 menu theme; the Navbar looks like the following image.

[image: Example Menu]

---

As shown in the above image, the home page is hard-coded to be "active." 
What I need help with is making each link appear in this "active" state when selected/active. When a user clicks on one of the NavLinks, the image should go from grey to black/orange. When a link is not selected (or inactive), the image should go from black/orange back to grey. Active/selected links should also have black text while inactive links have grey. So far, all I have found out is how to toggle a singular class but not multiple. Overall, I really don't know how to go about this at all. 
How do I toggle one NavLink active and change its image while also changing all other NavLinks to inactive, changing their images as well? Any help would be much appreciated. I have the following code for my Navbar so far:

```js
export class NavMenu extends Component {
  static displayName = NavMenu.name;

  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
this.state = {
  collapsed: true
};
  }

  toggleNavbar() {
this.setState({
  collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
});
  }

  render() {
return (
  <Navbar
    fixed="bottom"
    className="navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ng-white border-top mb-3"
    light
  >
    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
    <Collapse
      className="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse"
      isOpen={!this.state.collapsed}
      navbar
    >
      <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            tag={Link}
            id="navHome"
            className="text-dark active"
            to="/"
          >
            <img
              src="/Images/NLUnactiveImg.png"
              alt="Unactive Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
              hidden
            />
            <img
              src="/Images/NLActiveImg.png"
              alt="Active Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
            />
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            tag={Link}
            d="navResume"
            className="text-dark inactive"
            to="/resume"
          >
            <img
              src="/Images/NLUnactiveImg.png"
              alt="Unactive Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
            />
            <img
              src="/Images/NLActiveImg.png"
              alt="Active Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
              hidden
            />
            Resume
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            tag={Link}
            d="navContact"
            className="text-dark inactive"
            to="/contact"
          >
            <img
              src="/Images/NLUnactiveImg.png"
              alt="Unactive Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
            />
            <img
              src="/Images/NLActiveImg.png"
              alt="Active Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
              hidden
            />
            Contact
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            tag={Link}
            d="navFetch"
            className="text-dark inactive"
            to="/fetch-data"
          >
            <img
              src="/Images/NLUnactiveImg.png"
              alt="Unactive Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
            />
            <img
              src="/Images/NLActiveImg.png"
              alt="Active Link Image"
              height="45"
              width="45"
              hidden
            />
            Fetch data
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
      </ul>
    </Collapse>
    <div>
      {' '}
      <PlaySound child={this.state.child} />{' '}
    </div>
  </Navbar>
);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can build this functionality out manually but it's a little tricky, it should come with whatever library you are already using. Are you components custom or are you using a library like bootstrap. Please tell us what library you are using so that we can help.

Comment: @JoshPittman Hey! Thank you for commenting! I am believe I am using an "integrated" form of bootstrap called Reactstrap, but also have some custom components. To be ultra specific, I used VS to create a .NET MVC Core project using React.js; it came with Reactstrap and I am still trying to feel my way around it. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove you css (images) into a seperate css file. Make a class and put your css into that. Something like this

```
<NavLink tag={Link} d="navResume" className="text-dark inactive resumeImage" to="/resume">
    Resume
</NavLink>;
```

in your css file

```
.resumeImage {
    //declare your image styles here
}
```

Repeat above for all your Navlinks.

Now keep those styles which you only want to apply to the active link in a seperate class and apply that class to all the Navlinks like below

```
<NavLink
    tag={Link}
    d="navResume"
    className="text-dark inactive resumeImage"
    activeClassName="activestyleclass"
    to="/resume"
>
    Resume
</NavLink>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current URL and change the image based on the url since active class should be depend on the url too.
You can use react hook useLocation to get current URL.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Component= () => {
  const [pathname, setPathname] = useState('/');
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setPathname(location.pathname);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <NavLink to="/" className="navbar-item">
        {pathname === '/' ? (
          <img src="/images/navbar/home_active.png" alt="Home" />
        ) : (
          <img src="/images/navbar/home.png" alt="Home" />
        )}
      </NavLink>
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass a render prop as children to customize the content of the
>  based on the active and pending state, which is useful to
> change styles on internal elements.

```
<NavLink to="/dashboard">
        {({ isActive}) => (
           <>
              <img src={isActive ? activeMenuIcon : menuIcon} alt="" />
              <div>Search</div>
           </>
        )}
    </NavLink>
```

ref:https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).